# AEM - CRXDE: cq:Dialog not showing for component

Tags: html, aem

Starting out with AEM by using CRXDE, and making a structure component for a **header hero** component that will show a title and subtitle.

I wanted to add a `cq:dialog` by just copying the `libs/wcm/foundation/components/title/cq:dialog` component, and pasting it inside the **hero** component. There are two values: `jcr:title` and `jcr:subtitle`. When it comes to those values, they do display if I manually add them to my page from the `contents` directory.

The problem that I am facing is that the *dialog* is not showing at all when I hover over the **hero** area of the website from the `editor.html` view.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do. You want to have a hero component but you copied the dialog of the "title" component. This dialog does not contain a field for `jcr:subtitle`. Can you please provide more information about your component. Especially what JCR nodes you have: component node and all its child nodes.

Comment: I am just trying to get the dialog to show up for the authors. The end goal is to get a dialog which I just copied the title one as a template then I'll be modifying it to add more fields like the subtitle one I mentioned.

Apparently I got it to work when I added the `cq:EditConfig` node, but I had seen it done without it from a video. I would link the video, but it is from a paid member website (Pluralsight).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `jcr:subtitle`. This property name appears to be outdated/invalid and will most likely throw an exception related to the node type definition. Simply use `subtitle` and you should be fine.

Comment: I did not realize there are only certain keywords with anything `jcr:`. I thought it was a standard to make input properties that start with that prefix. Good to know, and i'll make the adjustments.

Comment: You can pretty much rely on https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrConstants.html for the defined JCR properties. But these might only be applicable under specific conditions (when creating files in JCR for example). Feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: As much as your answer was helpful, but it did not solved the actual problem with my dialog not showing up on the Author dashboard.

Comment: This problem still occurs?